# How to manipulate variables in a class, from a different class?

Tags: java, class

Working on a simple tic-tac-toe game in Java.

I have a class named `GameHelpers`. This class should contain useful methods for the game. The game happenes in another class.

A method in `GameHelpers` is `ResetGame()`. This method is supposed to set the text on all the 9 buttons (the tic-tac-toe board) to blank, set them enabled again, and set a variable to 1.

This is it's code:

```
public class GameHelpers {

    public void resetGame(){
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                buttons[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`buttons[]` is an array of JButtons inside the main class of the game, `TicTacToe`.

This method was previously inside the main class of the game, `TicTacToe`. But now that it's in a different class, it can't reach the buttons in the `TicTacToe` class and manipulate them.

I created get and set methods in `TicTacToe`, but how do I activate them from `GameHelpers`?

How can I make the method in `GameHelpers` work?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the source button that was pushed via the ActionEvent's `getSource()` method.

so for example:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvenet e){
     JButton sourceBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
     String text = sourceBtn.getText().trim(); 
     if (text.isEmpty()) {   // see if x/o assigned yet
       sourceBtn.setText(....);  / "X" or "O" depending on logic
     }
}
```

This way, all 9 buttons can share the exact same ActionListener, and the program will still work.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> Why the trim() thing?

I figure that you've got a tic-tac-toe game going on here, and if so, that you don't want to add an "X" to a JButton that already displays either X or O text. If perchance you've given the JButton a space `" "` for text, the `trim()` will get rid of any leading or trailing whitespace and will change the text to `""`, and you'll know that it can accept new text, either an "X" or an "O". If you don't need it, then don't use it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
But I only wrote:
JButton sourceButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
sourceButton.setText("X");
Why the trim() thing?